# How can I inject a service into another one in Java, SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**Hello, I've been trying to use a service into another one but I get null. Does anyone know how can I inject it correctly?
(My ClassServiceB has its @Service annotation)**

**This is my service class...**

```
@Service
public class ClassServiceAImpl implements ClassServiceA {

   @Autowired
   ClassServiceB classServiceB;

   @Override
   public ClassOutDto searchDriverForOrder(InputDto inputDto ) {

   classServiceB.doSomething(); //In this part classServiceB is getting null

   ...
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't activate or didn't properly configure the package scanning.

Comment: Thank you guys, my mistake was that in class B I didn't have injected my DAO class... @Service public class ClassServiceBImpl implements ClassServiceB{ private ClassBDao classBDao;....}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use @Autowired in the constructor class? It is easier when you want to do unit tests and the recommendation to do injection depended. Would be like this:

```
       @Service
       public class ClassServiceAImpl implements ClassServiceA {
    
       private ClassServiceB classServiceB;
    
       @Autowired
       public ClassServiceAImpl(ClassServiceB classServiceB) {
          this.classServiceB = classServiceB;
       }
    
       @Override
       public ClassOutDto searchDriverForOrder(InputDto inputDto ) {

       classServiceB.doSomething(); //In this part classServiceB is getting null
       ...
     }
   }
```

Don't forget that your ClassServiceB must also be annotated with @Service. Your interface should not be rated. If that doesn't help, share more of the properties, interface and ClassServiceB.

Comment: Thank you, well, my mistake was that in class B I didn't have injected my DAO class...                                                                           
@Service
public class ClassServiceBImpl implements ClassServiceB{
 private ClassBDao classBDao;....}